# Do US private schools ask Chinese students to get referral letters from the Chinese Consolidated Benevolent Association to join them?

Tags: realism, ip-man-4

In *Ip Man 4*, the principal of an American private school asks Ip Man to get
references from the CCBA so his son can be considered for enrollment in the school.

Do US private schools ask Chinese students to get referral letters from the Chinese Consolidated Benevolent Association to join them?

Comment: From the Wikipedia page for the CCBA, "The [CCBA] had many dealings with local and federal governments, exerting influence in a variety of methods." It certainly seems like influence with the CCBA could certainly have made it easier to get into a school, but I'm not sure a reference from the CCBA would have been necessary for Chinese students.

Comment: Related meta question https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4699/why-was-this-realism-question-marked-as-closed